# Why is adding an element to a SortedSet permited despite SortedSet being an interface rather than a class

Tags: java, interface, sortedset

Can someone explain me why this code compiles and runs fine, despite the fact that [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is an interface and not a concrete class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] nums = {4, 7, 8, 14, 45, 33};

    List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(nums);
    TreeSet<Integer> numSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    numSet.addAll(numList);

    SortedSet<Integer> sSet = numSet.subSet(5, 20);
    sSet.add(17);
    System.out.println(sSet);

}
```

It prints normally the result: `[7, 8, 14, 17]`

Furthermore, my wonder is heightened by the fact that the SortedSet cannot be instansiated (expectedly). This line does not compile:

```
SortedSet<Integer> sSet = new SortedSet<Integer>();
```

However, if I try the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] nums = {4, 7, 8, 14, 45, 33};

    List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(nums);
    numList.add(56);

    System.out.println(numList);
}
```

it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. I reckon, this comes from the fact that List is an interface and cannot be handled as a concrete class. What is true about `SortedSet`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SortedSet is an interface.  This means you can have a reference to a class which implements this interface, but not create an instance of class with no implmenetation.

In the case of Arrays.asList() it returns a class which wraps the original array.  You cannot add to the original array so add is not supported.  If you use set for example, you will alter the original array.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(nums);
```

`Array.asList()` return  **an array** but **wrap** in List interface. So The list is still backed by the array and the arrays are the fixed size, you cannot add/delete elements from array. That why next line will throw exception `UnsupportedOperationException`.

For more detail, java `ArrayList` is still an array behind, but it has some helper method, for you to delete/add elements (you can wiki for phrase `resizeable array` for more detail.

Secondly, `SortedSet` is an interface. Interface like abstract class, can have reference to a class that implements/extends its, but it's not **concrete class**, so you cannot create object on those (interface nor abstract class).

And I see, both two questions you ask, maybe relate to `polymorphism` in OOP, I recommend you wiki this phrase too.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

SortedSet is an Interface not a class.

You could only instantiate from non-abstract classes.

List is an interface, too.
But according to the doc of List the method "add" is optional, meaning there is NO guaranty to be supported.

I think **optional** methods contradicts the idea and contract of interfaces.
The better would be to have an NonModifyableList (without add) and a ModifyableList (with add).
The current poor choice is probably a result the history and the wish not to break old code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking why you can successfully refer to an object as a SortedSet (or any interface type).  When a variable's type is an interface or abstract class, that means the variable must hold an object which inherits that variable's type (or the null object).

While every object's actual type has to be a concrete class, the `sSet` variable is only required to hold an instance of some class that inherits (implements) SortedSet.

In the case of the `TreeSet.subSet` method, it returns an object whose type is an internally defined concrete class which implements SortedSet.